# Ionicons are not loading in browser build (ionic build --prod) - Ionic Application

Tags: angular, svg, ionic4, ionicons

In my ionic project, ionicons are loaded while doing ionic serve. But while taking browser build (ionic build --prod), svg files are getting downloaded but not appending to the  component.

This screenshot showing icons are loaded in browser when ionic serve was given.

[image]

This screenshot showing app without icons. You can see svg are downloaded in network tab but not visible in screen.
(Ionic build --prod).

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMnfs.png)

Comment: and your code, can you share full code plus ionic version

Comment: Thanks Sergey Rudenko. I have added screenshot that contains code and package.json file